# Is it possible to expand the measure in dimensional regularization?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, integration, perturbation-theory, dimensional-regularization

In the dimensional regularization scheme, four-dimensional integrals are analytically continued from their $d$-dimensional counterparts, i.e.,

$$\int d^4 x\, f(x) \longrightarrow d^d x\, f(x)\,, \tag{1}$$

with, e.g., $d := 4 - \varepsilon$.

My question is simple: can the measure be expanded in $\varepsilon$?
I doubt it, but if yes I guess it should take the form

$$d^d x \sim d^4 x - \varepsilon A\, d^4 x + \ldots\,, \tag{2}$$

where $A$ is to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

1. In practice [dimensional regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization) (DR) is not done by expansion of the measure factor $$d^dx$$ (whatever that is mathematically supposed to mean).
2. Instead one typically considers the exact analytic expression for the full integral $$I(d)~=~\int\! d^dx~f(x,d)$$ [of the specific class of integrands $f(x,d)$ that one is interested in] as a function of the integer dimension $d\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

   In favorable cases, there exists a natural analytic continuation of $I(d)$ to (a region of) the complex $d$-plane, which then serves as a definition for the DR scheme.

Comment: In some situations (e.g. the $\varepsilon$-expansion), higher powers of $\varepsilon$ might be needed. Some integrals are too hard to be calculated in arbitrary $d$, so I am looking for an alternative method to relate those higher powers to $4d$ integrals. I should say that I don’t think that it is possible.